# Calculating Percentage off Three Values

Tags: windows, percentage

how do you calculate percentage of three values.
For Example
Total amount 51000
Partner one 31000
partner two 20000

what is the easiest way to calculate the exact percentage?
i tried doing it using windows calculator but it's too difficult because its so hard to find the absolute value with nothing on top. even after going as low as 5 digit behind decimal point.

found it hard way that partner one is 60.784314% but even that's not perfectly correct, that percentage sums up to 31000.00014 which again is 00014 on top.
is there any easy way to find the exact percentage.

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming or software development at all.

Answer (score 0):

The exact percentage is

31000/51000 = 31/51

and

20000/5100 = 20/51

those are the "exact" values. Both numbers are irreducible - so any decimal representation is just an approximation.

You might use an "advanced" calculator like i.e. wolfram alpha who gives you the exact result as a fraction and approximated decimal representations.

Comment: Thank you David, that sure help me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
31000 / 51000 * 100 = 60.7843137254902%

(60.7843137254902 / 100) * 51000 = 31000

20000 / 51000 * 100 = 3.92156862745098%

(3.92156862745098 / 100) * 51000 = 20000